# Any idea of wait times for a visa from US?

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

husband applied for a visa last Friday at the American embassy in London having had a previous minor conviction 19 years ago. He had a visa 10 years ago and was approved for a new one last week. We were told it the correct papers will be emailed to him but this could take 6 months. Just wondered if anyone has received theirs before the 6 months?
Many thanks

Comment: Exactly what is he supposed to be receiving that is supposed to take six months?

Comment: A tourist visa, he had a business one before

Comment: A b2 visa, anyone experienced this?

Comment: You can look up [processing times](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/wait-times.html/) yourself; in London it's currently five working days. So something else is going on here; please add in all the details you omitted.

Comment: Are you sure that he was approved?  Was the term 'waiver of ineligibility" mentioned?

Comment: My apologies it is a waiver of ineligibility.

Comment: Stacey, please edit into your original question all of the details. Comments may go away, but the question will be more permanent.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times they send everything before 6 months. You should have the contact info NVC or USCIS or an agent, and you could follow the status with them. You could also check the status online.